# How to assign class with highest frequency to each row of a data.frame in R?

Tags: r, class, dataframe, pattern-matching, frequency

i have the following table:

```
mymatrix <- matrix(c(34,11,65,32,12,9,32,90,21,51,45,23), ncol=3)
colnames(mymatrix) <- c("pos", "neg", "neutr") # class
rownames(mymatrix) <- c("1 -1 0", "-1 -1 0", "0 -1 1", "0 0 1") # patterns
mytable <- as.table(mymatrix)
mytable

#         pos neg neutr
# 1 -1 0   34  12    21
# -1 -1 0  11   9    51
# 0 -1 1   65  32    45
# 0 0 1    32  90    23
```

now i have new data with three columns. each row contains one of the patterns "1 -1 0", "-1 -1 0", "0 -1 1" and "0 0 1". so for example, my new data looks like this:

```
one <- c(  1,  1,  0, -1, 0,  1, 1)
two <- c( -1, -1, -1, -1, 0, -1, -1)
three <- c(0,  0,  1,  0, 1,  0, 0)
mydf <- data.frame(one, two, three)
mydf

#   one two three
# 1   1  -1     0
# 2   1  -1     0
# 3   0  -1     1
# 4  -1  -1     0
# 5   0   0     1
# 6   1  -1     0
# 7   1  -1     0
```

now i want to get a fourth column in mydf that assigns the class (pos, neg, neutr) to each row in mydf. the class with the highest frequency should be assigned.

it should look like this:

```
#   one two three    four
# 1   1  -1     0    pos  # (because for this pattern (1 1 -1), "pos" gets highest frequency in mytable.)
# 2   1  -1     0    pos
# 3   0  -1     1    pos
# 4  -1  -1     0    neutr
# 5   0   0     1    neg
# 6   1  -1     0    pos
# 7   1  -1     0    pos
```

how can i do that?

thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the first step you could learn the mapping from triple to label, and then you could look up the mapped value for each row of `mydf`:

```
maxes = apply(mytable, 1, function(x) colnames(mytable)[which.max(x)])
mydf$four = maxes[match(paste(mydf$one, mydf$two, mydf$three), rownames(mytable))]
mydf
# mydf
#   one two three  four
# 1   1  -1     0   pos
# 2   1  -1     0   pos
# 3   0  -1     1   pos
# 4  -1  -1     0 neutr
# 5   0   0     1   neg
# 6   1  -1     0   pos
# 7   1  -1     0   pos
```